# What is a simple ReactJS Internationalisation library?

Tags: reactjs, internationalization

What is a simple library for making a react app support multiple languages, I have looked at https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl and http://airbnb.io/polyglot.js/

I am currently building a ReactJS app that has to support both English and German, something that has features like languages packs that for example will contain all the days, months in German, I should not have to provide that.

Thanks in advance.

Note: I have actually done a ton of Googling.

Comment: What is your conclusion by now?

Comment: I had to build out a library that did exactly what I needed.